# Combining 3 AT&T U-verse modems to form 1 Aggregate Connection?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem, bonding

I need a faster internet connection. I am thinking about getting 3 AT&T U-verse modems, each providing me 18x1mbps. Is there an effective way to combine all 3 modems to form 1 aggregated connection, 54x3mbps? I have 6 computers and I would like to have 4-5 of them connected directly to the connection via wired connection and the other 1-2 connected via wireless. Is this possible? How do I do this?

Comment: You understand you would need 3 accounts just not 3 modems right?  There are cheaper options....

Comment: u-verse has a 45Mbps tier, is it not available in your area?

Comment: @Ramhound that depends...  rural areas and small towns may only have one broadband option even still in 2015.

Comment: Rural areas have businesses; they don't use the same plans that non-commercial lots use.  Just saying there are other options

Comment: Yes, I understand I will have 3 accounts. No there are no cheaper options. Bonded T1 lines are ridiculously priced. That is why I am trying to go this route.

Comment: Do you want up to a single stream at that speed or something sitting between your computers and the internet load balancing? The former is probably impossible without ISP assistance, the latter is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you could try...

Equipment Needed:

- 3 X AT&T U-verse modems
- 1 X Load balancer

  1. Connect modems, and connect to internet once on each
  2. Connect Load Balancer to combine modems
  3. Enjoy faster internet

OR

you could get FiOS or VDSL to improve speeds

Comment: Sadly FiOS isn't available to most of the USA.  http://fiberforall.org/fios-map/

Comment: eek... didn't know that, I'm in NZ, however VDSL, or a Load balancer would be the OPs best option

Comment: But a load balancer won't actually give me faster speeds, it will just load balance correct?

Comment: That is indeed correct

Comment: ^ is exactly right... It will load balance the PCs to get more equal speeds